# passar 2 parametros no evento OnClick do botão

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código que gostaria de passar os ID **txtCodEmpreendedor** e   **txtNomeEmpreendedor** dos campos abaixo como parametro para o evento **AdicionarEmpreendedor();**

```
<script>
    function AdicionarEmpreendedor(codigo, item) {
        //código
    }
</script>

<div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label style="color:cornflowerblue">ID</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" id="txtCodEmpreendedor" class="form-control" placeholder="Código" style="margin-left: -42px; width:92px;">
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="txtNomeEmpreendedor" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Empreendedor" style="margin-left: -42px; width:273px;" />

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top: 165px" id="divBotao">
            <button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="AdicionarEmpreendedor();">Confirmar</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Você quer passar esses ids de forma dinâmica, sendo que eles podem mudar? Ou é algo fixo?

Comment: alguma razão especial? não seria mais prática na *function* pegar os valores dos campos?

Comment: @DavidAlves serão dinâmicos

Comment: @RicardoPontual Não, porque eu vou armazenas as informações digitadas em localStorage no browser e regastar em outra view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se for passar de forma fixa é simples:

```
<div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top: 165px" id="divBotao">
    <button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="AdicionarEmpreendedor('txtCodEmpreendedor', 'txtNomeEmpreendedor');">Confirmar</button>
</div>
```

Mas é mais interessante, já utilizá-los direto na função, a não ser que você usará ela em outros locais com outros nome e id.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-secondary adicionar_empreendedor" data-dismiss="modal">Confirmar</button>

<script>
$(document).on('click','.adicionar_empreendedor',function(){
var txtCodEmpreendedor = $("#txtCodEmpreendedor").val();
var txtNomeEmpreendedor = $("#txtNomeEmpreendedor").val();
/* SUA FUNCAO CONTINUA */
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Eu sugiro dessa forma:**

```js
var btns = {
  gravar: document.getElementById('btn-gravar'),
  ler: document.getElementById('btn-ler')
};

var txts = ['txtCodEmpreendedor1', 'txtCodEmpreendedor2'];
var val = [];
btns.gravar.addEventListener('click', function(){
  txts.forEach(function(elem, idx){
    val.push(
      {   
        "Value" :document.getElementById(elem.toString()).value
      }
    )
  });
  
  localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringfy(val))
})

btns.ler.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('values')));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtCodEmpreendedor1" />
<input type="text" id="txtCodEmpreendedor2" />

<br>

<button id="btn-gravar">Gravar</button>
<br/>
<button id="btn-ler">Ler</button>
```

**Obs.:** Se quiser usar o localstorage, sugiro que faça fora deste snippet.